# How to improve Gmail's inline reply formatting?

Tags: gmail, gmail-text-editor

When someone replies inline to one of my messages, their text is hardly distinguishable from mine. Is there a setting or a hack to improve this?

For example:

[image]

Comment: Ask your contact to use other font settings when replying inline :)

Comment: I wish it were that easy. Google appears to do it's own formatting on inline replies. When someone sends me an email from Outlook with inline replies it comes back the same way, regardless of the formatting they specify on their end.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: Use user styles.

One alternative could be [Gmail quote colors and font sizes](https://userstyles.org/styles/60083/gmail-quote-colors-and-font-sizes). I didn't tried it yet.

From https://userstyles.org/help/other

> #### How user styles are different than user scripts
>
> User styles exist mainly to change the way things look. They are
> written with CSS, the same language that web sites use to control
> their appearance. Most browsers allow for user styles out of the box
> (with varying degrees of ease).
>
> User scripts exist mainly to change the way things act. They are
> written with JavaScript, the same languages that web sites use to
> create certain dynamic behaviours. Most browsers do not allow for user
> scripts out of the box. Greasemonkey is a well-known extension that
> adds user script support to programs.
>
> There exists a fair bit of overlap between user scripts and user
> styles. Some things can be accomplished with either method. User
> styles can change the user interface in Mozilla-based programs such as
> Firefox and Thunderbird, while user scripts cannot. User scripts can
> add behaviour to web sites, while user styles cannot. In general, it
> is recommended that if something can be done with user styles instead
> of user scripts, it should be done with user styles instead of user
> scripts. This is because user scripts can cause a site to flicker, as
> they have to wait for sites to load completely before firing, while
> user styles are not under this restriction. User styles are also
> generally easier